# How to re initialize variable (CCS 102)(Program C)

Tags: c

after making progress and rewriting most of the code for our calculator project, i run into a problem.

as the title suggest i need help with reinitializing the variable after loop or in every loop.

problem:

[image]

It should to like this:

[image]

as you can see instead of prompting an error it still calculate, suggesting that the inputed int was stored in my variable. which i maybe wrong or something but if i cannot fix these i make more progress.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//bool function
bool isInteger(double val)
{
    int truncated = (int)val;
    return (val == truncated);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //local variable
    double a, b;
    char operation, option = 'y';
    
    //loop
    while(option == 'y' || option == 'Y')
    {
        //system("cls");
        printf("Enter number and operator to solve:\n\nExapmple [a + b][a - b][a * b][a / b]\n");
        scanf("%lf %c %lf", &a, &operation, &b);
        
        // nested if
        if(isInteger(a) && isInteger(b))
        {
            if(operation == '+')
            {
                printf("Result: %.1lf\n\n", a + b); //ouput result
            }
            else if(operation == '-')
            {
                printf("Result: %.1lf\n\n", a - b); //ouput result
            }
            else if(operation == '*')
            {
                printf("Result: %.1lf\n\n", a * b); //ouput result
            }
            else if(operation == '/')
            {
                printf("Result: %.1lf\n\n", a / b); //ouput result
            }
            else
            {
                //output error
                printf("Invalid Operater!\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //output error
            printf("Input is not a digit!\n");
        }
        //output selection
        printf("Do you want to retry [y]/[n]?");
        option = getch(); //not recommended but just a small project
        //scanf("%c", &option); -- stops the loop
    } //end loop
}
```

Comment: The problem is not that values are being retained in `a` and `b` but that you are not checking `scanf` to see whether it successfully read and converted the three items. `scanf` returns a result. Test it to see whether it is 3, for three items converted and assigned. If it is not, print an error and either exit the program or read characters until a new-line character is seen, ending the current line of input, then try again. (This will not handle end-of-file or I/O errors correctly, but you can leave that out for now.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil so what is proper way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In your second example (i.e., second time around), this line

```
scanf("%lf %c %lf", &a, &operation, &b);
```

tries to read an *a* into a double which will cause `scanf` to fail and return early.

Check the documentation of `scanf` and you'll see that it returns the number of values read and will set `errno` on failure. These must be checked before `a`, `operation` and `b` can be safely used.

Comment: So how do fix this or proper way to do this?

Comment: It's already in the answer - check the number of matches read (and compare it to how many matches you expect, which is three in this case) and check `errno`.

Comment: _Ie_, you are ignoring the return value of [scanf](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fscanf.html); `int ret = scanf(...); if(ret != 3) ...`.